# alias must be in the Bash sub process

Tags: bash, process

How alias in Bash can be in the forked sub process Bash as get failed on:

```
alias al='echo hello '
$ al foobar
hello foobar

$ alias al='echo hello ' ; bash
$ al
bash: al: command not found
```

How to have it on the latter Bash as exactly functional as is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, already defined aliases in a parent-shell can't be exported(*made available*) to sub-shells/processes but can be made available to sub-shells by sourcing a file in which they are defined e.g. `~/.bashrc` ... Which means, in other words, redefining them in the sub-shells.

Functions, on the other hand, can be exported with `export -f name` ... So, you can use a function instead like so:

```bash
$ function al { echo "hello $1"; }; export -f al; bash
$
$ al
hello
$
$ al again
hello again
```